# I have a list and I remove index with compragenson also need to remove the next line after removed index

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
data_accounts = [2,8, 3,7, 4,10, 5,20]
data_accounts_limit = [2,4,5]
data_accounts = [x for x in data_accounts if x not in data_accounts_limit]
```

I need to remove also 8,10 and 20 how to remove them any help.Also 3,7 need to stay in same order in the list.

Comment: add them to the data_accounts_limit list?

Comment: On which criteria do you decide to remove 8, 10 and 20 ? You need rules

Comment: yes I make it thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create another list to remove those elements.

```
data_accounts = [2,8, 3,7, 4,10, 5,20]
data_accounts_limit = [2,4,5]
data_accounts = [x for x in data_accounts if x not in data_accounts_limit]

remove = [8, 10, 20];
data_accounts = [x for x in data_accounts if x not in remove]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, he wants to find remove the elements behind the elements that get removed on the first run

Comment: If it was that easy he would have done it because it seems he knows about

Answer (score 0):

```
for each_ac, each_p in zip(data_accounts[0::2], data_accounts[1::2]):
        for each_a in data_accounts_limit:
            if each_ac == each_a:
                data_accounts_limit.append(each_p)


data_accounts = [x for x in data_accounts if x not in data_accounts_limit]
```